# Compare subarrays of 2-dimensional array in Ruby and show result array with existing and missed items

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, comparison

You have a 2-dimensional array of strings:

```
[
    ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
    ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
    ["AAA", "CCC", "DDD"],
    ["AAA", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
]
```

You need to compare each subarray with other subarrays to get result as a 2-dimensional array which will show whether each string present in each subarray or not (if not - it should be **nil**) like this (**RESULT**):

```
[
    ["AAA", nil, "AAA", "AAA"], 
    ["BBB", "BBB", nil, nil], 
    ["CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC"], 
    ["DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD"], 
    [nil, nil, nil, "EEE"]
]
```

How to write a function that takes an initial array and returns array like in the RESULT example?

Comment: So what is the question? Share your ideas / code / findings. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I understand your question but I can see it is a challenge to express it precisely. I suggest you explain there are two steps. Let `arr` be the given array. The first step is to create an array `a` that contains all the unique elements in `arr.flatten` in the order in which they appear. Then you wish to create an array `b` containing `a.size` arrays of size `arr.size` such that `b[i][j]` equals `a[i]` if `arr[j]` contains `a[i]`, else it equals `nil`. Note that once you have a precise statement of the problem the solution becomes straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [
    ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
    ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
    ["AAA", "CCC", "DDD"],
    ["AAA", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
]
```

```
all = arr.reduce(:|)
  #=> ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
arr.map { |row| all.map { |s| row.include?(s) ? s : nil } }.transpose
  #=> [["AAA",   nil, "AAA", "AAA"],
  #    ["BBB", "BBB",   nil,   nil],
  #    ["CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC"],
  #    ["DDD", "DDD", "DDD", "DDD"],
  #    [  nil,   nil,   nil, "EEE"]]
```

See [Array#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-7C) (array union) for calculating `all`.

`transpose`'s receiver equals

```
arr.map { |row| all.map { |s| row.include?(s) ? s : nil } }
  #=> [["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD",  nil],
  #    [  nil, "BBB", "CCC", "DDD",  nil],
  #    ["AAA",   nil, "CCC", "DDD",  nil],
  #    ["AAA",   nil, "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

if list has the next values:

```
list = [
        ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
        ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
        ["AAA", "CCC", "DDD"],
        ["AAA", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
    ]
```

then

```
def method_name(list)
  handled_list = list.flatten.uniq
  handled_list.each_with_object([]) do |item, res|
    res << list.map{ |sub_array| sub_array.find{ |s| s == item } }
  end
end
```